# Initializing QVector of QImages

Tags: qt, initialization, qimage, qvector

I am fairly new to Qt. It is the first framework I have worked with. I am writing a blackjack game using Qt. It seems to me that I should store the images of each card in a container class such as `QVector`. The container type would be of `QImage`. So I would have a declaration such as `QVector<QImage> cards;` Perhaps this is not the best way about approaching this problem so any alternative suggestion is of course welcomed. However, regardless, I would like to know if it is possible to initialize the container during the declaration. I have not been able to solve this so my solution is the following:

```
// Deck.h
class Deck
{
public:

    Deck();
    void shuffle();    // Creates new deck and shuffles it.
    QImage &popCard(); // Removes first card off deck.

private:

    void emptyDeck(); // Empty the deck so new cards can be added

    QVector<QImage> cards;
    QQueue<QImage> deck;
};

// Deck.cpp
Deck::Deck()
{
    cards.push_back(QImage(":/PlayingCards/Clubs 1.png"));
    cards.push_back(QImage(":/PlayingCards/Clubs 2.png"));
    cards.push_back(QImage(":/PlayingCards/Clubs 3.png"));
    cards.push_back(QImage(":/PlayingCards/Clubs 4.png"));
    // continue process for entire deck of cards...
}
```

This seems to be painfully tedious especially if I consider adding a different style of playing cards later on, or if I give the user an option to change the style of the cards at run time. What would be an efficient design to this?

Comment: "if it is possible to initialize the container during the declaration" - in c++, no.
"This seems to be painfully tedious" - yes, but you will get the experience and the next project (or may be this one) you will make better.

per aspera ad astra. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if it is possible to initialize the container during the declaration

Yes you can since **C++11**:

```
QList<int> list{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Well about your question one of the way can be:

1. Create in resources all types of your images style calling like template, for example: "*Name **n**.png*", where **n** - number from 1 to 54 (cnt of cards with Jokers);
2. Create some `QList<QImage>` (I think it'll be better then QVector);
3. Create some QMap for searching correct template easy;
4. Create some enum class for template map;
5. Write a function that change images of your cards by selected enum.

However it is very light codding. I think there is more usefull ways and there is a lot of other more beauty ways to do this game and logic. But as part of your question here some code (can be not very right, cause write as is):

```
// Somewhere in global
enum class CardsTemplate: {
    Clubs,
    SomeTemp1,
    SomeTemp2,
    ...
    SomeTempN
}
```

**.H file:**

```
private:    
   QList<QImage> _images;
   QMap<CardsTemplate, QString> _imagesMap {
       {CardsTemplate::Clubs, QString("Clubs")},
       {CardsTemplate::SomeTemp1, QString("SomeTemp1")},
       {CardsTemplate::SomeTemp2, QString("SomeTemp2")},
       ...
       {CardsTemplate::SomeTempN, QString("SomeTempN")}
   }

public:
    Deck(CardsTemplate temp);
    void setNewTemplate(CardsTemplate temp);
```

**.CPP file:**

```
Deck::Deck(CardsTemplate temp){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 54; i++)
        _images << QImage(QString(":/Playing cards/%1 %2.png")
                   .arg(_imagesMap.value(temp)).arg(i));
}

void Deck::setNewTemplate(CardsTemplate temp) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= _images.size(); i++)
        _images[i] = QImage(QString(":/Playing cards/%1 %2.png")
                     .arg(_imagesMap.value(temp)).arg(i));
}
```